# Using a function from a wasm module in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

I've decided to learn Rust alongside Web Assembly to get into more cloud computing. I'm trying to make a Rust app that connects to a Redis cache and increments a value each time a function is called. I then want to export that function with the wasm-bindgen to use it with JavaScript in a website that will call the function each time the website is refreshed and display the value on screen. Here is my current rust code:

```
use redis::{Client, Commands};
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn increment_counter() -> i32 {
    let client: Client = Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").unwrap();
    let mut con: redis::Connection = client.get_connection().unwrap();
    let key: &str = "counter";
    let value: i32 = con.get(key).unwrap_or(0);
    let new_value: i32 = value + 1;
    let _: () = con.set(key, new_value).unwrap();
    new_value
}
```

and here is my HTML & JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Increment Value Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Current value:</h1>
    <div id="counter"></div>
    <script type="module">
import { increment_counter } from "./pkg/increment.js";

const counterElement = document.getElementById("counter");

function updateCounter() {
  const count = increment_counter();
  counterElement.textContent = count;
}

updateCounter();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been compiling the rust code with `wasm-pack build --target web` and trying to use the increment.js file that makes. I host the server with http-server from npm but get this error in the browser:

```
Uaught SyntaxError: The requested module './pkg/increment.js' does not provide an export named 'increment_counter' (at (index):11:10)
```

But I think the rust code does export the function correctly with wasm-bindgen and I get no errors/warnings from the compiler so I am really confused as to where I am going wrong.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wasm-pack build --target web
```

this will create `pkg` folder and inside you will javascript file. `pkg` is a different module, your front end is a different module. to reach out to `pkg`, i think you should add it to the `package.json` inside your front end project.

```
"dependencies": {
    // what ever the name of the .js file in pkg directory
    "increment": "file:../pkg",  
  },
```

in your front end

```
// note that in dependencies I named the module as increment
// all pub variables decorated with #[wasm_bindgen] can be imported
import init, { increment_counter } from "increment";

init().then((wasm) => {
   // implement logic here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`'./pkg/increment.js'` exports a default function that must be called before you can use any of the exported functions. Here is an example:

```js
import init, { increment_counter } from "./pkg/increment.js";
async function run() {
  await init();
  // ... insert rest of code here ...
}
run();
```